# Updating external objects/variables within async Promise.all

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise

When updating values within a `Promise.all()`, are the following results guaranteed? My understanding is that the internal function would be happening in parallel, but how would that affect the result?

- `a` will be 6 (0 + 1 + 2 + 3)
- `b` will have length 8 (length of d * 2)

  - order is not guaranteed
- `c` will have length 3 and all the key/value pairs are guaranteed except for `c['a']`

```
const networkCall = async () => {
  // takes time
}

const update = async (i) => {
  let a = 0;
  let b = [];
  let c = {};

  const d = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a'];
  
  await Promise.all(d.map(async (i, index) => {
    await networkCall();
    a += index;
    b.push(i);
    b = [i, ...b]
    c[i] = index;
  });

  console.log(a);
  console.log(b);
  console.log(c);
}

update()
```

I looked through similar questions but didn't find a satisfactory answer.

Comment: Sounds correct. You already pointed out the things that are "variable" about it. You can btw easily test this by doing `await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)))` in `networkCall`.

Comment: *in this code* the answer is "yes". That's in no way an indication that every code will behave the same. This is not related to `Promise.all()` itself but the nature of the async operations done. E.g., `a += b.length + await getSomeAsyncNumber()` might lead to unpredictable results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When updating values within a `Promise.all()`...

`Promise.all` is unrelated to updating the values of `a`, `b` and `c`. `Promise.all` will just take an array of promises and create a new promise. That's it. That new promise is returned before any asynchronous code has executed. It doesn't influence how some callback function is making updates. The promise retured by `Promise.all` is used here to make sure the `console.log` calls are only made when all asynchronous code has executed.

> My understanding is that the internal function would be happening in parallel,

"Parallel" could have different meanings... It is not that each statement separately could run in round-robin with another one. In this particular case it is guaranteed that for a *given* `index`, the four statements below the `await` are executed as *one uninterrupted* block without any other JavaScript running. Only when that block is completed (and the callback returns) can there be a possibility to have the same block executed for another execution context of that block (with a different `index` variable and value).

> `a` will be 6 (0 + 1 + 2 + 3)

Yes, this is guaranteed when `console.log(a)` is executed, even though it could for instance have been calculated as 1 + 0 + 3 + 2.

> `b` will have length 8 (length of `d * 2`) -- order is not guaranteed

Yes. Order is not guaranteed, but the array is guaranteed to be a "palindrome": `b[i] === b.at(-i-1)`

> `c` will have length 3 and all the key/value pairs are guaranteed except for `c['a']`

Yes.

Comment: "it is guaranteed that for a given index, the four statements below the await are executed as one uninterrupted block without any other JavaScript running" Do you have any references for this?

Comment: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-jobs-and-job-queues  *"Execution of a Job can be initiated only when there is no running execution context and the execution context stack is empty."*